# background img with rgba value is not working on firefox

Tags: css

I am using `<img src="" />` element and there use some css background linear-gradient-rgba value, url;  It's work in all messor browser but not working on Firefox only.
    Plz help me. Thanks

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/mdsa/MLjez/

Answer (score 0):

You could control it with `opacity`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/MLjez/1/

```
.romi {
    background: url('http://dev.tastery.com/images/experience/experience-1-main35488.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Did you check on firefox? It's not working still now.

Comment: Need to attach in css display:block; it's work all mezor browser.